# Reset an auto-increment counter in object

Tags: c#

I have a `class` containing an auto-increment counter like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static object sync = new object();
    private static int globalCount;
    private int idUnique;

    public MyClass()
    {
        lock(sync)
        {
            idUnique = ++globalCount; 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, in my app, when the user deletes an instance of MyClass, I'd like it to reset the counter and recalculate the counter for the remaining instances of MyClass.

For example:

```
MyClass a has IdUnique of 1  
MyClass b has IdUnique of 2  
MyClass c has IdUnique of 3  
MyClass d has IdUnique of 4
```

The user deletes `b` & `c` so the app updates the remaining instances so `a has a IdUnique of 1` and `d has a IdUnique of 2`.

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea... Quite complex to make I think...

Comment: How does one "delete an instance of a class?"

Comment: Each instance of the class is attached to a treeNode inside a treeView. The user deletes a node and thus deleting the instance

Comment: If you delete the one with Id 5 for instance, then just decrement the id of any with an Id > 5.

Comment: So, `IdUnique` neither identifies an object (because what used to be 4 is now 2) nor is unique (2 has been reused to relate to different objects)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah, that's basicly it :/ changed the name to `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like it very much... (to be clear: the code should work correctly, but I don't LIKE it). Note that `Delete()` is a O(n) operation now... And it could be converted in a `Dispose()` (plus the automatic call from the finalizer).

Some test code:

```
var insts = new[] { new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass() };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (object[])insts));
insts[1].Delete();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (object[])insts));
insts[3].Delete();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (object[])insts));
insts[0].Delete();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (object[])insts));
insts[2].Delete();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (object[])insts));
```

and the class... Note that I'm keeping a static `SortedSet<>` that contains all the instances. I'm even creating an "ordering" of `MyClass` (the `IComparable<MyClass>`)

```
class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass> {
    public static SortedSet<MyClass> Instances = new SortedSet<MyClass>();
    private static object sync = new object();
    private int idUnique;
    private int originalIdUnique;

    public MyClass() {
        lock (sync) {
            idUnique = Instances.Count > 0 ? Instances.Max.idUnique + 1 : 1;
            originalIdUnique = idUnique;
            Instances.Add(this);
        }
    }

    // It could be a Dispose()!
    public void Delete() {
        if (idUnique == int.MinValue) {
            return;
        }

        lock (sync) {
            Instances.Remove(this);

            if (Instances.Count > 0 && this.idUnique < Instances.Max.idUnique) {
                var instances = Instances.GetViewBetween(this, Instances.Max);

                foreach (var instance in instances) {
                    instance.idUnique--;
                }
            }

            idUnique = int.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Id: {0} (OriginalId: {1})", idUnique, originalIdUnique);
    }

    #region IComparable<MyClass> Members

    public int CompareTo(MyClass other) {
        return idUnique.CompareTo(other.idUnique);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @xanatos, it works great. I'm still gonna make some improvements to the overall app code to make it more "likable"

Answer (score 3):

Such a thing is more of a property of a *collection* of your objects than anything else.

If you were to organise your object instances into an array-type structure, then you could use the position of your object in that array as the unique identifier.

(When deleting an item, you delete it from the array causing all elements to the "right" of it to shift back by one, if you get my meaning.)

Comment: So, in my case, since all the instances are attached to a node inside a treeview, I create a collection of all these nodes and add the Id depending on the position in the collection?